# twitter-bootstrap-rails gem not rendering the menu bar properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am using "twitter-bootstrap-rails" gem in my Rails app, I generated the scaffolds and made one of the view page as the root page. In the root page the menu items are by default getting rendered as active and when I use the URI(like localhost:3000/posts/new) the menu is getting rendered properly.

Also the text on the buttons are rendering in black color.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zdgqe6kpm6vob7/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-11%20at%2010.16.11%20PM.png?n=50050245

https://www.dropbox.com/s/noz2bta6418df72/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-11%20at%2010.16.27%20PM.png?m

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, because you are too long to post your code. I tried to help by reading your post

First, about active menu

You can add this to your `app/helpers/application_helpers.rb`

```
 def is_active?(link_path)
  if current_page?(link_path)
    "active"
  else
    ""
  end
 end
```

And on your views, menu view looks like :

```
<ul>
  <li class="<%= is_active?(root_path) %>">
    <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
  </li>
  ..
  ..
  ..
</ul>
```

Last, about link with black color. Because you have generated scaffold and that is generate  a `scaffolds.css.scss` file, you need delete it (`scaffolds.css.scss`). Style link with black color on this file.

Comment: Scaffolds.css.scss issue got resolved and what you said did the magic.

Coming to the menu's issue this is the code snippet - http://pastebin.com/SPCFDV8W

And am really interested in knowing why does this issue throws up?


Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got that fixed too, I was giving root_path as the link for all menu_item `<%= menu_item "Things you can't afford", "#" %> ` and hence they were getting highlighted. replaced them with other "#" for time being and it worked.